# integration of numeric data - Matlab

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab

I have multiple set of numeric data and I want to use Matlab to compute the integral.
I used two methods:

-Using "trapz" function of Matlab.

-Using "spline" function and then using the "integral" function.

In general, the second approach is more accurate, BUT:

In some cases the results have significant error. And even increasing the number of datas does not reduce error anymore. (e.g., although using 100k points are more accurate than 10k points, using 1 million or 10 million points have same error as 100k points).
The plot of the data is something like [image: this]

Is there any way to find the integral of a function like this accurately?

Thank you.

Comment: Try adaptive integration methods like quadgk but its an ugly function that will not be well modeled by polynomials used in Gaussian quadrature methods.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way than using polynomials?

Comment: Yes. For functions with singularities look at tahn-sinh quadrature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature

Comment: @arthur thanks. May i ask where is the singularity of my function? Because the value of the function is available for every x. Why does finding the area under the function is hard for Matlab?

Comment: @tio- The spikes are similar to singularities. Using regularly spaced samples of the function like trapz does, may miss most or all of the spike. Polynomial methods like Gaussian quadrature are poor because the polynomials do not model the spike very well. Read these algorithms to see that they are not magic. The algorithms have weaknesses. You might even have to find the spikes and split the integral in two parts placing the spikes at the end points of the tahn-sinh quadrature method.